# ASP.NET null reference to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two models:

**ApplicationUsers**: ( The default that comes with Identity framework )

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

and **Room**:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User1 { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User2 { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User3 { get; set; }
}
```

I created a new user at AppliactionUser:

[image: ApplicationUsers table]
And I manually added a new Room and reference to that User:

[image: Rooms Table]

**NOTE:** It might not seem from the images, but their ids are the same, I doubled-checked it, the reason it looks different in these pictures is because there's not enough space to display the full length.

But when I ran my web and wrote this code on Home Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var varForDebug = db.Rooms.Find(1); // Room id 1

        return View();
    }
```

and made a breaking point at **varForDebug** I couldn't see an ApplicationUser at User1:

[image]

Why is that and how it could be solved?

**Note:** I'm using: ASP.NET MVC Web Application (.NET Framework ) 4.6.1 with Identity.

**Note2:** Include wants only string parameter from some reason, whys that?

Maybe I should consider adding Room property to ApplicationUser?

Comment: Either enable lazy loading and make those properties virtual or follow the below answer about calling Include for each relationship you need to load like `Include("propertyname")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use    `db.Rooms.Include(r => r.User1).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == 1);`

and repeat that for User2, User3 etc.

Comment: I tried, tho it says: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'String' because it is not delegate type".

Comment: Yeah, Include() and Find() don't go together. I just took a gamble. Corrected.

Comment: Oh, and I'm thinking EF Core. I forgot the details for EF6.

Comment: It still insists to get String as a parameter in Include, it keeps saying: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'String' because it is not delegate type". I might need to add Room property to ApplicationUser?

Comment: Try `Include("User1")`

Comment: It works! thanks a lot, in order to repeat that for user 2 and 3, how it should look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198448/discussion-between-dorki-and-henk-holterman).

Comment: You can have multiple `.Include("...")`

Answer (score 2):

First, add the references:

> using System.Linq;

and

> using System.Data.Entity;

If you want to keep using the Find operation, use:

```
 var varForDebug = db.Rooms.Find(1); // Room id 1 `

 // Load the user 
 context.Entry(varForDebug).Reference(p => p.User1).Load();
```

or

```
db.Rooms.Include(r => r.User1).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==1);
```

Comment: Yeah but Include wants only String from some reason, how could it be solved?
Edit: Worked by using Include("User1") instead.

Comment: @Dorki have you added the reference using **System.Linq;** or **System.Data.Entity;**?

Comment: @Dorki I updated the answer. Please check if it improves the response to your question.